# IndexOutOfRangeException while using StringBuilder in nested for loops in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, indexoutofrangeexception, parallel.for

1. Getting Exception at line `convertedMatrix[temp] = matrix[i,j]`;
2. Exact Error:

   > IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
   >   System.Text.StringBuilder.set_Chars (Int32 index, Char value) (at /System.Text/StringBuilder.cs:line number)
3. Here is the code (in C#):

   ```
   public const int size = 4;
   public System.Text.StringBuilder convertedMatrix = new System.Text.StringBuilder(size * size);
   public char[,] matrix = new char[,]{'i','s','e','m','r','v','u','n','t','o','d','a'};

   public void Generate() {
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           convertedMatrix.Append(" ");
       }

       int temp = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
               convertedMatrix[temp] = matrix[i,j];
               temp += 1;
           }   
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: CS0846 A nested array initializer is expected

Comment: This does not even compile.. Please post your actual code.

Comment: This can't be your code, you initialized a multi-dimensional array with a one-dimensional array-initializer...

Comment: Here is the full code with other classes also:
[link](http://pastebin.com/SCmwVcHH)

Error is at Line No. 159.

Answer (score 2):

The `convertedMatrix` has `i` characters. In the line you get the error, `temp` can be up to (i-1)*(j-1) which is more than i.

You probably want to increase number of characters in `convertedMatrix`.

Comment: Here is the full code if you would like to provide a solution: 
[link](http://pastebin.com/SCmwVcHH)

Error is at Line No. 159.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys debugged it. As @yper said convertedMatrix had less characters. So the error was at line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    wordsLength[i] = 0;
    convertedMatrix.Append(" ");
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    wordsLength[i] = 0;
    convertedMatrix.Append(" ");
}
```

Thanks guys!